# How to connect php webservice to sql server 2008 r2

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, web-services, sql-server-2008

We are developing php webservice and our database is on sql server 2008 r2

/* sql connection string  */

```
     $link = mssql_connect('localhost','usrname','pass') or die('Cannot connect to the DB');     
     mssql_select_db('Data Source=PC-NAME;Initial Catalog=DBNAME.MDF;Persist Security Info=True',$link) or die('Cannot select the DB');

        /* grab the posts from the db */

        echo $query = "SELECT * FROM add_product WHERE prod_pos = '".$_GET['prod_pos']."'";
        $result = mssql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);
```

it gives fatal error on mssql_connect.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in service.php on line 11

So how to connect php webservice with sql server 2008 r2???

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download and install the sqlsrv extension from Microsoft. Look here for one option: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Note that the extension is no longer called "mssql" but is instead now "sqlsrv" so you'll want to use `sqlsrv_connect()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Got the Answer..............

```
    <?php
        $number_of_posts = $_GET['prod_pos']; 

        $format = 'json';

        /* connect to the db */

        $serverName = "(local)";

        /* Get UID and PWD from application-specific files.  */
        $uid = "usrname of sql server 2008";
        $pwd = "password";
        $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid, "PWD"=>$pwd, "Database"=>"db name" );

        /* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
        if( $conn === false )
        {
             echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
             die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }


        /* Query SQL Server for the login of the user accessing the database. */

        $tsql = "SELECT * FROM add_product WHERE prod_pos='".$number_of_posts."'";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
        if( $stmt === false )
        {
             echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
             die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }


        /* create one master array of the records */

        $posts = array();
        while($post = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt) ) 
        {
                $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
        }


        /* output in necessary format */

         if($format == 'json') 
         {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));
         }

        /* disconnect from the db */

        $stmt = null; 
        $conn = null; 

     ?>
```

Successfully connected to the sql server 2008 r2 database using php